# Twitter's activerecord-reputation-system gem + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, routes, rubygems

I am working with Twitter's new [activerecord-reputation-system](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/issues?state=open) gem, yet it doesn't seem to be registering in my app.

I ran to install (docs have a typo):

```
gem install activerecord-reputation-system && rails generate reputation_system && rake db:migrate
```

I've included it in my gemfile and tried pulling directly from github, as well as restarting my local server. The error is the following:

> ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `has_reputation' for #<Class:0x007fa7ed783ec0>):
>     app/models/post.rb:18:in`'
>     app/models/post.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>     app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:1:in`'

when I try to add votes to posts with this code:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_reputation :votes,
    :source => :user,
    :aggregated_by => :sum
end
```

When I try to add votes to users with the same code I get:

```
undefined method `has_reputation' for #<Class:0x007fa7efb70388>

app/models/user.rb:17:in `<class:User>'
app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

This error occurred while loading the following files:
   /Users/username/appname/config/routes.rb
```

routes.rb, Line 4:

> devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should require `reputation_system` in your app. You can do this by adding to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'activerecord-reputation-system', :require => 'reputation_system'
```

**Update:** As of version `2.0.0` you don't need to require `reputation_system` anymore:

```
gem 'activerecord-reputation-system'
```